Optimisation of Polynomial Fittting Process
I have built a multitvariate log link GLM model and I want to fit polynomials to some of the numerical variates (i.e. fit polynomials of order 1,2,3 etc to the relativities of the model). However, I would like the polynomial fitting process to be part of the overall optimisation of the model. For example if I apply a polynomial to one of the variates it will impact the fit of other variates, other variates will be optimised as the polynomial fitting process. It is possible to make the orthogonal assumption (just generate the variate polynomials independently, assuming no impact on other factors) but I would preferably not do this.
Can someone please give me some ideas and material to read up on in order to do this? I am also considering using Ridge Regression to do this.
Thanks

Welcome to Cross Validated! It is routine to include polynomial features in GLMs. What is the issue you see with just including the squares or cubed terms in the regression?

I am using third party software that does not have a polynomial fitting feature. So what I am hoping to do is to take the predictions, actuals and model relativities (but maybe I just need the residuals as I probably don't need the model relativities unless doing something very basic) from the  model built in this software and fit some polynomials on top of it (e.g. in Python).
So for example, I could strip out the effect of the variate of interest outside of the TP software and then fit a polynomial to it in Python outside using the residuals e.g. via Y = B0 + B1X1 +B2X1^2 + B3X2 + B4X3 ?

Just square or cube the variables and enter them as new features. The math does not know or care how the features are derived, if they come from other features.
